# Typescript issue when using Vue3 with Vuex4

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3

TS2345: Argument of type 'StoreOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin_2'.   Property 'install' is missing in type 'StoreOptions' but required in type '{ install: PluginInstallFunction; }'.

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store, key)
app.use(router)
app.use(...)
app.mount("#app")
```

store:

```
export interface RootState {}
const state: RootState = {}

export interface TypeState extends RootState {
  markdown: MarkdownState
  user: UserState
  fileTree: FileTreeState
  editor: EditorState
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<TypeState>> = Symbol("storeKey")
export const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = createStore({
  state,
  modules: {
    markdown,
    user,
    fileTree,
    editor,
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      paths: ["user", "fileTree", "markdown"],
    }),
  ],
})

export function useStore() {
  return baseUseStore(key)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your store like this:

```
export const store = createStore<RootState>({
  // ...
});
```

The `app.use` method expects a Vue plugin as its first argument. A Vue plugin is an object with an `install` method. In this case, an instance of the [`Store` class](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/8c1c5d9c9fdcd705ffd01ccdcb2212247f7d221b/src/store.js#L19) in Vuex.

As seen [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/8c1c5d9c9fdcd705ffd01ccdcb2212247f7d221b/types/index.d.ts#L48), the `createStore` method's return type is a `Store`. Which is what you want. So there is no need to specify a type for your `store` variable. The only thing you need to do is to provide your state type to the `createStore` method like mentioned.